# Im have built a program but I want print out the second input

Tags: java

The program averages out numbers that the users input but I want to take it to another level, I want to print out the second number the user inputed. Do I have to change and reconstruct the program or do I just input something simple?

```
import java.util.*;

public class InputHere
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        int counter= 0;
        int average;
        int total= 0;

        System.out.println("Enter 2 Numbers");

        while(counter < 2)
        {
            num= scan.nextInt();
            total=total + num;
            counter++;
        }
        average= total/2;
        System.out.println("The average is " + average);
    } 

}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
 import java.util.*;

public class InputHere {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        int counter = 0;
        int average;
        int total = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter 2 Numbers");

        while (counter < 2) {
            num = scan.nextInt();
            if (counter == 1)
                System.out.println(num);
            total = total + num;
            counter++;
        }
        average = total / 2;
        System.out.println("The average is " + average);
    }

}
```

Comment: I see you added a if statement.. Can someone explain the if statement? if(counter == 1)

Comment: why would counter not be == to 2?

Comment: @DanielAndrews you are counting from 0, which means the first number is when `counter is 0`, and the second number is when your `counter is equal with 1`

Comment: I understand that awesome! just because I want to get a better understanding. In my while loop can I just put while(counter < 1) since counter counts from zero. Why do I have to put 2?

Comment: @DanielAndrews if you put only `counter < 1` it will start at 0, then it will increase counter at 1 and will end the `loop`, so you will have only one number, not two.

Comment: @DanielAndrews you can use this if you want:
`while(counter <= 1)`

Comment: I so upset haha you made it so easy. Didn't realize you just needed a if statement. So I'm saying if counter equal to 1 it will print the second number I typed while its in the while loop?

Comment: Thank man. I'm in cis 100 so I'm basic basic thank you for being patience with me. Does it take practice to understand this because you made it so easy and it was easy just I have a hard time programming because I just don't fully understand what is what or what it can do